# Confirmation on re-written query

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, apache-tez

***Original query:***

```
SELECT CAST(cust_mart.acct_identifier AS STRING) as f0 
FROM   cts_work.cust_xref cust_mart 
GROUP BY cust_mart.f0;
```

Can I replace the above query with below query :

```
 SELECT DISTINCT CAST(cust_mart.acct_identifier AS STRING) as f0 
 FROM cts_work.cust_xref cust_mart;
```

***Reason:*** 
there is no aggregation so group-by does not make sense, but still confirming my approach I am running this query on hive using TEZ engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [EXPLAIN](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Explain) command and compare two query plans to check the difference. These queries should generate identical plans. `Group by` will work the same as `distinct` in this case. `DISTINCT` is also an aggregation, just another word for the same group by.